# How to hide/suppress pop-up icons in excel obscuring cell contents

Tags: microsoft-excel

Notice in the following screenshot that the "paste options" popup/icon is obscuring several cells.  How can that popup be suppressed (or relocated?)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> to hide it after pasting.

Alternatively, you can [disable this altogether](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/hide-or-display-the-paste-options-button-dace7144-924d-4bcc-a964-5fbe1f3fedab):

> 1. Click the File tab, then click Options.
> 2. In the Advanced category, under Cut, copy, and paste, clear or select the Show Paste Options button when content is pasted check box to hide or display the Show Paste Options button.

[image]

Here is how to [do it on `macOs`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/hide-or-display-the-paste-options-button-dace7144-924d-4bcc-a964-5fbe1f3fedab?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-gb%252farticle%252fhide-or-display-the-paste-options-button-on-a-mac-57ebf9ed-2040-4c29-80b5-44ff56cb13b4&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#ID0EAABAAA=macOS): go to `Preferences|Edit` and  unselect `Show paste options`:

> 1. On the Excel menu, click Preferences.
> 2. Under Authoring, click Edit.
> 3. Under Cut and Paste Options, clear or select the Show Paste Options check box.

Screenshot per @javadba:
[image]

Comment: This looks good but I'm macos:  i will accept this answer in a moment but will add another one for macos.

Comment: @javadba - On the linked page are [instructions for macOS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/hide-or-display-the-paste-options-button-dace7144-924d-4bcc-a964-5fbe1f3fedab?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-gb%252farticle%252fhide-or-display-the-paste-options-button-on-a-mac-57ebf9ed-2040-4c29-80b5-44ff56cb13b4&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#ID0EAABAAA=macOS).  Edit: Ah, thanks for editing the answer :D

Comment: `Esc` does not work. popup stays